# get id attribute of selected items in drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I have many drop down boxes with the name emp .so in the below code i am trying to print the id of the boxes but some how it is printing empty what am i doing wrong here

```
  var selected_emp = $('select[name="emp"]');
     selected_emp.children('option:selected').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != null)
        {
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }
     });
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your html code as well?

Comment: check whether id is set on options tag, because the same code is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your option elements have an `id` attribute?  Typically, `option` elements just have a value and the included text.  You could do something like this to print the id of the box and the selected value in the box:

```
 var selected_emp = $('select[name="emp"]');
 selected_emp.children('option:selected').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != null)
    {
       alert($(this).parent().attr('id') + ":" + $(this).val());
    }
 });
```

Or, to just iterate through the select boxes themselves:

```
$('select[name="emp"]').each(function() {
    alert(this.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zdU9K/

Or do you want it to alert when the select box changes?

Comment: Hi, i have many select boxes with name as emp, <select name="emp" id=1></select> <select name="emp" id=2></select>

Comment: ok, so you want to return the id's of all the select boxes with the name=emp